# Cname or A record for domains having ssl certifcate www.mydomain.com

Tags: iis, dns, ssl-certificate, cname, a-records

We have two `A` records pointing to same public IP address as:

- `www.example.com IN A 192.*.*.*`
- `example.com IN A 192.*.*.*`

We have certificate issued by Verisign to `www.example.com`. Now when the user types `https://www.example.com/xyz`, everything works fine as expected.

But when we use `https://example.com/xyz`, the browser throws an error:

> "There is a problem with this website's security certificate"

And asks the user to make decision if they trust and want to go ahead.

Now what should be best practice here:

1. Change certificate and get wildcard certificate `*.example.com`
2. Use following setting at DNS:

   - `www.example.com IN A 192.*.*.*`
   - `example.com IN CNAME www.example.com`
3. Write a HTTP module in .Net pipeline to redirect user if they type `example.com/xyz` to `www.example.com/xyz`. I know this is not recommended.

We would like to do something like what `chase.com` is doing. If you type `chase.com` it takes you to `https://www.chase.com/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the above. You should **get SSL certificate that covers two domains: `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com`**.

As per your proposals:

1) Having wildcard certificate for a single domain of `*.mydomain.com` will still give you an error when opening mydomain.com without any prefix. You may of course get a multidomain certificate for `*.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com`

2) For the sake of SSL, it doesn't matter CNAME or A - DNS used to get the address (A record) of your webserver, afterwards browser still expects SSL certificate to match exactly what you type in the address bar.

3) That would work for **http** requests, but when user types **https://mydomain.com**, browser checks SSL certificate **before** it processes the redirection request, and will still show the warning.

*P.S. You have this problem because CA industry is totally screwed. Their product pages all look like "super 256-bit encryption" (certificate have nothing to do with encryption strength), mobile support (be it mobile or mainframe, certficate is all the same), and "a free site-seal included" (site seal is a great name for a CA advertisement placed on your site).*

*All the not important things like is it's CRL or OCSP, or which domain names it covers at all - never mentioned.*

Comment: is it two seprate certificate or one certificate supporting two domains?

Comment: It's **one certificate** for **multiple domain names.** Two separate certificates work only with newer browsers, supporting Server-Name-Indication. With all the rest only one certificate will be used, and thus user will get a warning for the second name.

Comment: It is common for certificates to cover two names `www.example.com` and `example.com`, and again, CA bastards forget to mention it -  you have to contact support to know what you actually get.

Comment: @Julian I did not say that there's any need for a wildcard cert.

Comment: You're right @Sandman4, but you don't need a cert for two domains either.  You just need a regular http redirect.  No need to buy anything new.

Comment: @Julian: The original question reads _But when we use httpS://mydomain.com/xyz, browser throws...._ Whether it's important to have no warnings or not in this rare case, it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @Sandman4: Right you are.  All I saw was "We would like to do something like what chase.com is doing if you type chase.com it takes you to https://www.chase.com/".  Removing my answer (though I'd argue it makes sense it does not address the question as written).