# How do I setup SSL certificates for a web server's CNAME with NodeJS / ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, cname

I recently setup SSL certificates for a web server with NodeJS similar to the following manner and everything works great:

```
process.env.HTTPS_PORT = 3000; // Listen on port 3000 for HTTPS.
process.env.HTTP_PORT = 6000; // Listen on port 6000 for HTTP.

// Create HTTPS server all workflow.
https
    .createServer(
        {
            key: await fs.readFile('/etc/pki/tls/private/key.txt'),
            cert: await fs.readFile('/etc/pki/tls/certs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.crt'),
            ca: await fs.readFile('/etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt'),
        },
        app
    )
    .listen(process.env.HTTPS_PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Main server is running on: ${process.env.HTTPS_PORT}`);
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(`Failed to start main server: ${err}`);
    });

// Create HTTP server for redirection to HTTPS only.
http.createServer(app)
    .listen(process.env.HTTP_PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Redirection server is running on: ${process.env.HTTP_PORT}`);
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(`Failed to start redirection server: ${err}`);
    });
```

I'm listening on two ports, one serving HTTPS and the other HTTP. The HTTP server's purpose is to redirect to HTTPS only for which I have a route setup.

This setup works for the server's FQDN (app.subdomain1.domain.com). The server also has a CNAME (web.subdomain2.domain.com). From the [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158708/3906773) I've done, it looks like the CNAME needs to be handled separately as the browser still expects a valid certificate for the URL the user requests. It is expected that users will use either of the URLs to access the application.

I could not find much information on how I can setup SSL certificates with NodeJS / ExpressJS for such CNAMEs. Any information on this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate must match the domain given in the URL. The simplest way is have a single multi-domain certificate which includes all the domains. Another way is to have multiple certificates and create a different context for each . see [server.addContext(hostname, context)](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#serveraddcontexthostname-context) and [Serve two https hostnames from single node process & port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952255/serve-two-https-hostnames-from-single-node-process-port).